# Comparing currentTime of videojs with a list of numbers

Tags: javascript, compare, video.js

I am using videojs in my react application and I want to achieve something like this:

Things I have are :

- Current time of videojs getting continuously captured in a variable.
- an array of json each having startTime and endTime key.

What I want

- I want check whether the current time has the value between any of the startTimes and endTimes of the json.

Problem:

- As the current time of video player is a continuously changing quantity/value, I am not able figure out how to make a check whether it has the value between so many startTimeS and endTimeS.

What I tried till now (but obviously it is wrong)

```
 tags.map((item, i) => {
                if( item.time <= currentTime <= item.stopTime){
                    this.props.markerReachedAction(i);
                }
            })
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the condition with two implicit comparisons conjoined by an `&&` i.e.

```
if (item.time <= currentTime && currentTime <= item.stopTime)
```

Review the following snippet to see what is the problem. 1 < 3 < 2 should be false but it is computed as true.

```js
$('#a').html('Result of 1 < 3 < 2 = ' + 1 < 3 < 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"></div>
```

Since the value is being continuously updated and you need to perform the computation continuously as well. You should use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) along with clearInterval. There are examples of usage on the reference link that you may use.

Comment: ok but this doesn't address the real problem which  is currentTime changing continuously. How can I compare a variable which changes every millisec (or less than that).

Comment: Updated the answer. Use setInterval with 500ms or 1000ms and add the comparison to it. Make sure the mapping to item is done in the function.